# change kendo grid ui toolbar dynamically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo ui grid, and for initialization I pass create and edit button to grid toolbar like this :

```
var grid = elem.kendoGrid({
                        ...
                        toolbar: getToolBar(),
});
```

getToolbar function return an array list of buttons. now for example after user click on edit button I wanna add two new button with the name of Cancel and Save . I have used this code but I was useless :

```
var grid = elem.kendoGrid({
                        ...
                        edit: function (e) {
                            e.sender.options.toolbar = getCancelToolBar();
}
});
```

I wander how can I change this buttons on toolbar after user click on edit button .
any idea is welcome and thanks in forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify all button you need in `getToolBar()` function and then use CSS & JS to toggle them.

CSS:

```
.k-grid .k-grid-save-changes,
.k-grid .k-grid-cancel-changes {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var grid = elem.kendoGrid({
    ...
    edit: function (e) {
        e.sender.element.find('.k-grid-save-changes').show();
        e.sender.element.find('.k-grid-cancel-changes').show();
    }
});
```